# Scroll from bottom to top in a text message like modal with React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a modal in my website where you can send and receive messages. Like Twitter DM. When I open a conversation I have to scroll to the bottom to see the most recent message but I want the conversation to open at the bottom, so the first thing I see are the most recent messages. How can I do this?

This is what I got

```
            <Container>
              {messages.map(message =>
                message.user.id === currentUser.id ? (
                  <div key={message.id}>
                    <p style={textAlign: 'right'}>{message.body}</p>
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  <div key={message.id}>
                    <p style={textAlign: 'left'}>{message.body}</p>
                  </div>
                )
              )}
            </Container>


const Container = styled.div`
  margin-left: 5px;
  height: 34%;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 90%;
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses the latest React Hook feature, so you will need React 16.8+, and it makes use of functional components.

Here's a link to my [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-surf-g9qrc?from-embed). The code in the sandbox is shown below.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const styleMessageUserLabel = {
  borderRight: "1px solid black",
  padding: "0.105em 0.618em"
};

const styleMessage = {
  padding: "0.105em 0.618em"
};

function Message(props) {
  const { user, message } = props;
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", margin: "0.309em" }}>
      <div style={styleMessageUserLabel}>{user}</div>
      <div style={styleMessage}>{message}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

const styleList = {
  listStyleType: "none",
  padding: 0
};
const styleItem = even => {
  return {
    padding: 0,
    margin: 0,
    background: even ? "none" : "#EFEFEF"
  };
};
function Conversation(props) {
  const { messages } = props;
  const messageList = (
    <ul style={styleList}>
      {messages.map((m, i) => (
        <li style={styleItem(i % 2 === 0)}>
          <Message user={m.user} message={m.text} />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
  return <div>{messageList}</div>;
}

const exampleMessages = [
  { user: "user1", text: "hey" },
  { user: "user2", text: "yo sup?" },
  { user: "user1", text: "nmu?" },
  { user: "user2", text: "chillin'" },
  { user: "user1", text: "cool cool" },
  { user: "user2", text: "what's good?" },
  { user: "user1", text: "life man" },
  { user: "user2", text: "that's what I'm talkin' 'bout" },
  { user: "user1", text: "word" },
  { user: "user2", text: "fo sho" },
  { user: "user1", text: "you down for tonight?" },
  { user: "user2", text: "we good" },
  { user: "user1", text: "solid" },
  { user: "user2", text: "cu lata" },
  { user: "user1", text: "oh, forgot to ask" },
  { user: "user2", text: "u bringin food" },
  { user: "user1", text: "pizza" },
  { user: "user2", text: "cowabunga!" },
  { user: "user1", text: "party on!" },
  { user: "user2", text: "excellent!!" },
  { user: "user1", text: "*air guitar*" },
  { user: "user2", text: "*air bass*" },
  { user: "user1", text: "*air drums*" },
  { user: "user2", text: "totally rad" },
  { user: "user1", text: "awesome" },
  { user: "user2", text: "righteous" }
];

const styleApp = {
  fontSize: "1.618em",
  fontFamily: "sans-serif"
};
function App() {
  const messagesEndRef = useRef(null);
  const scrollToBottom = () => {
    messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };
  useEffect(scrollToBottom, [exampleMessages]);
  return (
    <div style={styleApp}>
      <Conversation messages={exampleMessages} />
      <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: This was really helpful, but in my case is moving the entire page and not just the scroll in the modal.

Comment: @alogon According to the docs: "The Element interface's scrollIntoView() method scrolls the element's parent container such that the element on which scrollIntoView() is called is visible to the user". You would only need to ensure that the element you are trying to scroll to is a direct child of the `<body>` or root element of your React site.

Comment: @alogon I've updated my answer to utilize the `scrollIntoView` at the highest `App` level. Does that help?